# how to erase extra space coming in implode function

Tags: php, implode

i have made an implode function. but in that some space is coming. Due to that my output is not coming correctly.

like:

```
     $category={"Software Developer",".Net Developer", "Android Developer"}

     $cat= "'".implode("','",$category)."'";

     $cat= 'Software Developer',' .Net Developer', ' Android Developer'
```

But result should be

```
      $cat= 'Software Developer','.Net Developer', 'Android Developer'
```

Please help me out How will i erase this space near to single quote.

Comment: use `trim` to do it.

Comment: What version of PHP accepts `$category={"Software Developer",".Net Developer", "Android Developer"}` as valid code?

Comment: After correcting your code - nothing really needs to be done - [see here](https://ideone.com/aG8wjB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `array_map` to trim the white spaces.

```
$category = array("Software Developer",".Net Developer", "Android Developer");

$category = array_map('trim',$category);

$cat= "'".implode("','", $category)."'";

echo $cat; //'Software Developer','.Net Developer','Android Developer'
```